# Preservation of chain condition under strategically closed forcing

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing, infinite-combinatorics

It is well-known that $\kappa$-closed forcing preserves $\kappa$-c.c. posets.  The same argument works for $\kappa$-strategically closed forcing.  Here is the definition:

> A poset $\mathbb P$ is *$\kappa$-strategically closed* if Player II has a winning strategy in the following game.  Player I chooses an element $p_0 \in \mathbb P$.  Given $p_\alpha$, the next player chooses $p_{\alpha+1} \leq p_\alpha$.  If $\lambda <\kappa$ is a limit ordinal, Player II must choose a lower bound $p_\lambda$ to the descending sequence $\langle p_\alpha : \alpha < \lambda \rangle$.  If the sequence fails to have a lower bound at some $\lambda < \kappa$, then Player I wins, and otherwise Player II wins.

**Question:** Suppose $\kappa$ is a regular cardinal and $\mathbb P$ is $\alpha$-strategically closed for all $\alpha<\kappa$.  Does $\mathbb P$ preserve $\kappa$-c.c. posets?

Comment: This might be related to the existence of square sequences. If $\kappa = \lambda^+$, $\square_\lambda$ is equivalent to "any $\lambda + 1$-strategically closed forcing is $\kappa$-strategically closed". There is a parallel equivalence for inaccessible $\kappa$. On the other hand, if $\kappa$ is Mahlo, then the $\kappa$-cc forcings of Easton support product of small forcings fails to be $\kappa$-cc after forcing a club through the singulars (which is essentially $\alpha$-closed for all $\alpha < \kappa$).